# Flow - Custom notification action is not allowed

Tags: visual-workflow, notification

I have this error message when I try to debug a flow that get records Id and send a custom notification :
*Error Occurred:
Custom Notification Action is not allowed*

I googled this error and found that : "Require User Permission for the Send Custom Notification Action" ==> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_mobile_notifications_release_update.htm&type=5&release=228
But I didn't get any details on how to resolve this.

I used the same flow to send custom notification on my personal Org and it worked perfectly.

Any of you have a solution to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm getting the same error in my Flow.

Answer (score 2):

You have to grant the permission to the users profile or using a permission set.
Somehow this seems to have changed with Spring'21 Release - I had also an issue with a flow which was suddenly not working anymore due to the missing permission.

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_mobile_notifications_release_update.htm&type=5&release=228

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out that Custom Notifications require a Target Id.

[image]